# Duality between orbifold and quasi-Hopf algebra (twisted quantum doubles)

Tags: group-cohomology, hopf-algebras, quantum-field-theory, orbifolds, conformal-field-theory

> **A quick Question**:
>
> - Is there some duality known between the **quasi Hopf algebra**
>   $D^\omega(H)$ of a finite group $H$ to an **orbifold model** (such as
>   [SU(2)/$G$ or SO(3)/$G$ orbifold of some group $G$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91178/orbifold-cft-of-su2-g-and-so3-g))? What is this duality relation precisely?

**Background**:

It is known (in theoretical physics) that the algebraic framework underlying **discrete H gauge theories** with 2+1D **Chern-Simons term** is the **quasi Hopf algebra** $D^\omega(H)$, i.e. the Chern-Simons term introduces a 3-cocycle $\omega \in H^4(BH,\mathbb{Z}) \simeq H^4(H,\mathbb{Z}) \simeq H^3(H,U(1))$ in the [cohomology group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dijkgraaf-Witten+theory) on the Hopf algebra $D(H)$. People in theoretical physics also call the **quasi Hopf algebra** $D^\omega(H)$ as another name: [**twisted quantum doubles**](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.3695), such as A Kitaev's (of Caltech) Annals of Physics 303, 2 (2003), Annals of Physics 321, 2 (2006). The background understanding of these topics (to me) would go to [Dijkgraaf-Witten theory original paper](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dijkgraaf-Witten+theory).

My question here is inspired by the observation in this [arXiv paper published in Nucl.Phys. B](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9203047). It stated that: "From the point of view of conformal ﬁeld theory it is of interest to mention that the
fusion rules of **$D^\omega(\mathbb{H}_8)$ for p = 1** coincide with the **level 1 SU(2)/($\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$)-orbifold** (cited [a paper by Dijkgraaf, Vafa, Verlinde, Verlinde](http://inspirehep.net/record/24933?ln=en)) **after
modding out the appropriate $\mathbb{Z}_2$ generated by 1** (see [Table 2 here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9203047))). Apparently, the algebraic structure of such non-holomorphic orbifolds is still determined by the ‘holomorphic’ Hopf algebra, be it deformed by a non-trivial 3-cocycle. To our knowledge, this has not been noticed before."

> **A detailed Question**:

It seems to me that there may have some duality between:
$$ \text{quasi Hopf algebra } D^\omega(\mathbb{H}_8) \text{ for p = 1} \leftrightarrow \text{level 1 SU(2)/($\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$) orbifold} $$
Here $p = 1$ is the 3-cocycles labeled of $H^3(\mathbb{H}_8,U(1))=\mathbb{Z}_8$ for $p$(mod 8) in $\mathbb{Z}_8$. How about other 7 classes other than $p=1$ in $p$(mod 8)?

> - Are there other some dualities exist for
>   $$D^\omega(\mathbb{H}_8) \leftrightarrow \text{? orbifold}$$
>   $$D^\omega(D_8) \leftrightarrow \text{? orbifold} $$
>   $$D^\omega(\mathbb{Z}_2^3) \leftrightarrow \text{? orbifold} $$
>   What is the general relation (if any, start with a finite group $H$)?
>   $$D^\omega(H) \leftrightarrow \text{? orbifold} $$

$D_8$ is a dihedral group with 8 group elements. $D^\omega(D_8)$ should have three labels of $p_1$,$p_2$,$p_3$ from $H^3(D_8,U(1))=\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  And $D^\omega(\mathbb{Z}_2^3)$ should have 7 labels of $p_j$ from $H^3(\mathbb{Z}_2^3,U(1))=\mathbb{Z}_2^7$.

ps. Excuse me that my mathematical background is not equivalent to a math PhD (but trained in physics), but this should be a research level question in mathematical physics. Please feel free giving comments/answers. Thank you for all who reply and support!

Comment: The question of finding orbifold constructions of fusion rings is very natural and interesting.  On the other hand, I don't see much evidence of a general duality here, since the rings are relatively small.

Comment: But are there some known examples appear between the twos? e.g. In my post I had provided one example. Examples are fine, it needs not to be very general. Physicists appreciate **(many) examples** more than **a theorem**. :)

Comment: See also [this post Phy.SE on orbifolds of SU(2)/G' and SO(3)/G'](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91178/orbifold-cft-of-su2-g-and-so3-g)  if there are available data in the literature, please let me know. Many thanks!

Comment: What it seems like you mean by duality is that the representation categories of $D^\omega(\mathbb H_8)$ for some $\omega$ and $SU(2)/(\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2)$ are described by the same fusion ring. To clarify then, it seems like what you are asking is this: Given $G,H$ finite groups and $\omega\in H^3(H,U(1))$, is there a G-orbifold theory with fusion ring isomorphic to the fusion ring for $D^\omega (H)$ and if so, what is there relationship?

Comment: The reason that I ask is that below, Marcel uses Muger's result to provide a $G$-orbifold CFT whose representation category is the representation category of $D^\omega(G)$. However, the statement from which you draw your inital observation goes no further than saying that the two are Grothendieck equivalent.

Comment: @ Matthew, thanks, please feel free update as an answer if you also have some inputs. I need to do some extra work or you may rephrase it to help digesting it.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the general question, from the point of view of conformal field theory
there is a rather trivial way to obtain (some)  $D^\omega(G)$. Namely, the representation category of the $G$-orbifold of a holomorphic (trivial representation category) rational conformal field theory is $\mathrm{Rep}(D^\omega(G))$ for some $[\omega]$, see Corollary 3.6. in 
http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2537

<del>But I have now idea if</del> as Scott pointed out as a comment all finite groups $G$  <del>(I suppose yes)</del> can be obtained this way;  one has to find a holomorphic theory with an action of $G$, for example the Moonshine CFT for the Monster group etc. Then for a given $G$ I also have no idea which $[\omega]$ arise this way.

I think it also follows conversely, that if a CFT has $\mathrm{Rep}(D^\omega(G))$ as representation category, then it is a $G$-orbifold of a holomorphic theory.
<del>But then I don't understand the non-holomorphic examples the op mentioned.</del> In the non-holomorphic examples you have to mod something out to become (the dual of) $D^\omega(G)$

Comment: @ Marcel: I thought the $D^\omega(H)$ and (if any) its corresponding $G$-orbifold, (such as the example in my post), the $H$ and $G$ are not necessarily the same groups? Are you identifying $H=G$ for some cases? Thanks.

Comment: Any finite group embeds in a sufficiently large symmetric group, and hence in the automorphism group of a sufficiently large tensor product of $E_8$ CFTs.

Comment: @ S. Carnahan, thanks, can you rephrase automorphism group and $E_8$ statement to the context of our posted question? (I could not fully grasp, are you teaching me something?)

Comment: @ Marcel, do you know any examples of orbifold describing $D^\omega(\mathbb{Z}_2^3)$, $D^\omega(\mathbb{H}_8)$ or $D^\omega(D_8)$?